# How to create an unordered list with children list from a simple list

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have this list:

```
<ul>
   <li class="level0">First item</li>
   <li class="level1">Second item (children of level0)</li>
   <li class="level2">Third</li>
   <li class="level3">Forth</li>
   <li class="level2">Third</li>
   <li class="level3">Forth</li>
   <li class="level4">Fifth</li>
   <li class="level4">Fifth</li>
   <li class="level2">Second</li>
   <li class="level3">Third</li>
   <li class="level2">Second</li>
</ul>
```

and I want to do this with this list in javascript or jQuery

```
<ul>
   <li class="level0">First item</li>
   <ul>
        <li class="level1">Second item (children of level0)</li>
        <ul>
            <li class="level2">Third</li>
            <ul>    
                <li class="level3">Forth</li>
            </ul>
            <li class="level2">Third</li>
            <ul>
                <li class="level3">Forth</li>
                <ul>
                    <li class="level4">Fifth</li>
                    <li class="level4">Fifth</li>
                </ul>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li class="level2">Second</li>
            <ul>
                <li class="level3">Third</li>
            </ul>
            <li class="level2">Second</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

If I can do this it will greatly help displaying it with something like an accordion in jQuery.

Thx!

Comment: First of all, your resulting markup is wrong. You cannot have a `<ul>` element after a `<li>` element. The nested list (`ul`) has to be inside a `li`.

Comment: what on earth can make you try to do this!!?

Comment: @AHMEDEL-HAROUNY the class value and a bit of jQuery :)

Comment: Second, stackoverflow is not the appropriate forum to ask people for work. We would love to help you out with a specific issue you'r having, but it seems that you have nothing.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

Comment: Looks like the question was pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/J8LP4/

```
var re = /\d+$/;

$( "ul li").detach().each( function() {
    doit( this, +this.className.match(re)[0] );
});

function doit( li, level ) {
    var cur = $( "ul:first"),
        prev = cur,
        ul;
    while( level-- ) {
        cur = $( "ul:first", cur );
        if( !cur.length ) {
            cur = $( "<ul>" ).appendTo(prev);
        }
        prev = cur;
    }

    cur.append(li);
}​
```

Comment: Please don't encourage this kind of poster.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame SO gets these kinds of questions million times a day, if they're simple people will answer anyway. I thought it was interesting enough problem to answer

Comment: @LynHeadley convert the string to a number. The result of `+"1"` is `1` for example

Comment: @Esailija thats a nifty little shorthand. I usually do `*1` but that is shorter in some cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! This will do nicely!